# Gunicorn worker restarts when exception is thrown

Tags: django, gunicorn

In our `django` app run through `gunicorn` a worker restarts whenever there is a exception thrown in a call which is not handled. This also causes other processes to fail like socket server.

However if I run as `dev` which is without `gunicorn`, any exception thrown is just printed out to console and application keeps on working smoothly. Also sometime I feel they are getting randomly restarted.

How can I have the same behavior as in dev i.e. worker doesn't restart on an exception.

Below is the gunicorn config. Gunicorn version 19.7.1

```
$VIRT_ENV/gunicorn -c config.py utrade.wsgi:application \
                          --log-level=debug \
                          --timeout=30 \
                          --access-logfile=- \
                          --access-logformat="%(r)s %(s)s" \
                          --log-file=-
```

config.py

```
bind = 'unix:/code/internal.utradesolutions.com/tanmay.garg/web/web/utrade/run/gunicorn.sock' 
workers = 5 
daemon=True
```

Comment: What version of gunicorn are you running? Also, are you able to post the command and arguments you use to start gunicorn?

Comment: @WillKeeling included relevant information